# Convert.ToInt32(string) giving wrong values

Tags: c#

I am getting weird numbers when I am parsing my string using the [convert.toint32](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.toint32?view=netframework-4.8)

```
var check = "82567";
Convert.ToInt32(check[0]) //I get 56
Convert.ToInt32(check[0].ToString());// I get 8
```

Can someone help me make sense of this

Comment: Both are right.  check[0] is a character, the int value is its ascii code, 8 in a string is 8 so returns 8

Comment: This is expected behaviour

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`check[0]` is a single character -- the character '8'. This means that you call the [`Convert.ToInt32(char)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.toint32?view=netframework-4.8#System_Convert_ToInt32_System_Char_) overload, which:

> returns a 32-bit signed integer that represents the UTF-16 encoded code unit of the value argument

`'8'` has the value 56.

`check[0].ToString()` returns a string, and so you call [`Convert.ToInt32(string)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.toint32?view=netframework-4.8#System_Convert_ToInt32_System_String_), which returns:

> A 32-bit signed integer that is equivalent to the number in value, or 0 (zero) if value is null

Answer (score 3):

There's nothing wrong here.

Your first call is to [`Convert.ToInt32(char)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.toint32?view=netframework-4.8#System_Convert_ToInt32_System_Char_) which just promotes the `char` to `int`. The value of `check[0]` is a `char` with a value of 56 - the UTF-16 value of '8'.

Your second call is to [`Convert.ToInt32(string)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.toint32?view=netframework-4.8#System_Convert_ToInt32_System_String_) which parses the string as a number. The string "8" is parsed to the value 8.